# How to get .pro file from the set of qt files

Tags: qt, qt5, .profile, seafile-server

I was trying to modify the source code of this open source project https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-client
As I can see it contains `.ui, .qrc`  etc files which is used in Qt, but there is no `.pro` files present in his repository. So how to get the `.pro` file for this repository code. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was the **Cmake** project , you should install CMake in your system and build it like this :

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

OR use [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-client/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) instead of `.pro` .

Comment: can I open ```CMakeLists.txt``` inside ```qt``` like a ```.pro``` file?

Comment: yes , drag and drop it inside qt creator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qmake` to generate the `.pro` file for this repository.
Just do the following steps:

1. Clone the `repo`.
2. `cd` into the `repo`
3. Run the following command

```
qmake -project -r *
```

It will repeatedly look into the directory and it's sub-directory files and will generate required `.pro` file for you.
You can learn more about this at below given link:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html#project-mode-options